# problems when loading an external page with .load, some JQuery code is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm loading a div from an external page with .load() and everything works well with it, this is the jquery code (it's included in all the pages so there are not missing .js files):

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( " #window " ).click(function() {
            $('.loadiv').fadeIn("fast");
            $('.loadiv').load($(this).attr("href") + " .windows-wrapper");
            $('#blackout').fadeIn("fast");
            $('#close').fadeIn("fast");
            return false;
        });
        $("#close").click(function() {
            $('.windows-wrapper').fadeOut("fast");
            $('#blackout').fadeOut("fast");
            $('#close').fadeOut("fast");
        });
            $("#blackout").click(function() {
            $('.windows-wrapper').fadeOut("fast");
            $('#blackout').fadeOut("fast");
            $('#close').fadeOut("fast");
        });

        //change css properties from parent divs
       $(' #child').focus(function(){
      $(this).parent().css( "border", "3px solid #4ec5da" );
    });
        $(' #child').blur(function(){
      $(this).parent().css( "border", "3px solid #D5D5D5" );
    });
    });
    </script>
```

but this last piece of code that allows me to change some css properties isn't working when I call the div from other page with .load(), but if I go directly to the page the code works well.

```
   //change css properties from parent divs
   $(' #child').focus(function(){
  $(this).parent().css( "border", "3px solid #4ec5da" );
});
    $(' #child').blur(function(){
  $(this).parent().css( "border", "3px solid #D5D5D5" );
});
});
```

I don't know what could be the problem, I'd be really thankful if you help me to figure it out. finally This is the way I use to call the functions.

```
<a id="window" href="register.php">Registro</a>
```

Comment: Any errors in console? Try to use jQuery instead of $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

Use

```
//change css properties from parent divs
$('.loadiv').on('focus', '#child', function () {
    $(this).parent().css("border", "3px solid #4ec5da");
});
$('.loadiv').on('blur', '#child', function () {
    $(this).parent().css("border", "3px solid #D5D5D5");
});
```

Comment: Genius I use this and works perfectly when loading from .load but stop working when I use the page directly... so I suppose I'll use your code for .load and the old code too for directly access (or have a better Idea?). thanks anyway.

Comment: @user3777499, Use `document` instead of `'.loadiv'` that will work in both pace